# sql query related

Tags: sql

Hi I have an "Student" table with below records

```
INSERT into Student(studId,name)
Values(1,A)
values(2,B)
values(3,C)
values(4,D)
```

I have a "Department" table with below records

```
INSERT into dept(deptId,Deptname,Emp Id)
Values(D1,Phy,1)
values(D2,Maths,2)
values(D3,Geo,3)
```

How can i find the student who does not belong to any department i.e. in this case the result should be "D".
I know the left outer join would return all the records from the student table but i am only interested to get 1 record i.e.: of student "D".

Comment: This is not a forum to ask people to do your homework.

Comment: Look into something like "where dept.deptid is null"

Comment: Any chance you could improve your subject? Any question about SQL is "sql query related"

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Student
WHERE   studId NOT IN (SELECT EmpId FROM dept)
```

Find all `Student.studId` entries that do not already exist in the `dept.EmptId` column as an entry. (Assuming I read your table correctly)

---

Ideally though, you should probably break out the "Student" and "Department" and creating a joining table (maybe called) "Student_Department" that links the keys of each table.

```
+--------------+       +--------------------+        +--------------+
| Student      |       | Student_Department |        | Dept         |
|--------------|       |--------------------|        |--------------|
| studId       | <-----| studId             |    .-> | deptId       |
| name         |       | deptId             | --'    | name         |
| ...          |       +--------------------+        | ...          |
+--------------+                                     +--------------+
```

This allows you to only have to define a student and department once, but can assign one student to multiple departments, one department to multiple students, or any combination therein.

Comment: Hey. How did you make that textualized (if that's word) diagram? [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16479425/1309352).

Comment: @BleedingFingers: Index and middle fingers (hunt'n'peck) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo-code:

```
select *
from students
where id not in(select a.id from students a 
                inner join department b where b.id in('D1','D2','D3'))
```

Comment: Aaron; Thanks for the response but the inner query what you have mentioned will be ok if the department ids are limited but what if the department ids are too many, in that case will the below query work?"select * from students where id not in(select a.id from students a inner join department b where b.id in(select distinct deptID from dept))"

Comment: You need to know what you don't want to return.  Therefore, if you know the dept you don't want to return just change the `IN` in the subquery to `NOT IN` the dept id you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with some commenters that this sounds like a homework problem, I'll answer with a question...

> I know the left outer join would return all the records from the student table but i am only interested to get 1 record i.e.: of student "D".

OK, let's say you run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Student
LEFT OUTER JOIN dept ON Student.studId = dept.EmpId
```

You'd get the results:

```
studId    name    deptId    deptName   EmpId
1         A       D1        Phy        1
2         B       D2        Maths      2
3         C       D3        Geo        3
4         D       NULL      NULL       NULL
```

Can you add a `WHERE` clause to this query that will filter out only the data you want? :)

Comment: Oh well.  Hopefully reading through these answers and comments will still do anonymous some good.

Comment: For all those who think this is a homework question, let me clarify its not so. every trivial query has its own importance. here i am trying to understand different cases of join, hence thought of getting confirmed with some experienced guys in this forum. Also I dont have a sql query analyzer handy dut to which i am posting these queries..also pls see my above comments in which I have mentioned the sql query from my end too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.name
FROM Student s
LEFT JOIN Dept d ON d.empId = s.studId
WHERE d.empId IS NULL
```

Comment: I realize that this is a old post. But could you please elaborate.