# How to easily outline arbitrary (data) structures in text?

Tags: emacs, editor, structure, draw

So I came across [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project):

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

and [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html#adjacency-list-relationships):

```
root --+---> child1
       +---> child2 --+--> subchild1
       |              +--> subchild2
       +---> child3
```

and was wondering what tool(editor packages/bundle etc) does one use in order to outline and edit such structures easily/programmatically.

*PS: My preference is towards emacs but for the sake of completeness I will appreciate if other editors/tools were included in the answer.*

Answer (score 2):

The second example is clearly more complex, and I'm not going to address it, but outline-mode/minor-mode is going to work nicely for the indentation-based tree, so here's an approach for that, with outline headings based on an arbitrary repeated prefix string (four spaces in this example, but configurable as required).

If you load/evaluate the code below, and then load the data file (with the local variables included), then you can hide/show branches with <kbd>SHIFT+TAB</kbd> and promote/demote branches with <kbd>SHIFT+LEFT</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT+RIGHT</kbd> (cursor keys). All the other `outline-minor-mode` functionality is also available, of course.

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
            urls.py
        wsgi.py

;;; Local Variables:
;;; my-outline-prefix: "    "
;;; eval: (my-outline-minor-mode 1)
;;; End:
```

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "<S-tab>") 'outline-toggle-children)
(global-set-key (kbd "<S-left>") 'outline-promote)
(global-set-key (kbd "<S-right>") 'outline-demote)

(defvar my-outline-prefix "    "
  "Prefix string denoting a single outline level for `my-outline-minor-mode'.")

(defvar my-outline-max-level 20
  "Maximum number of levels for `my-outline-minor-mode'.")

(define-minor-mode my-outline-minor-mode
  "Outline levels based on repetitions of `my-outline-prefix'."
  0 nil nil
  (outline-minor-mode 1)
  (setq-local outline-level 'my-outline-level)
  (setq-local outline-regexp (format "\\(%s\\)*" 
                                     (regexp-quote my-outline-prefix)))
  (setq outline-heading-alist '())
  (let ((level 0)
        (level-prefix ""))
    (while (< level my-outline-max-level)
      (setq outline-heading-alist (cons (cons level-prefix level) 
                                        outline-heading-alist)
            level (1+ level)
            level-prefix (concat level-prefix my-outline-prefix)))
    (setq outline-heading-alist (nreverse outline-heading-alist))))

(defun my-outline-level ()
  "Counts how many times `my-outline-prefix' appears at the start of the line."
  (let* ((data (match-data))
         (start (car data))
         (end (cadr data))
         (indent (- end start)))
    (/ indent (length my-outline-prefix))))
```

Comment: could you please elaborate "With local variables included"?...any other word or hint on the second example?

Comment: With a local variables list included in the data file, as I showed in the answer. See `C-h i g (emacs) File Variables RET`. But as I've made the indent value default to four spaces, you could also just load the data file and type `M-x my-outline-minor-mode` in this instance.

Comment: *Maybe* outline mode could still be made to work in the second example, but I suspect only for expanding and collapsing the existing structure. Someone else might have a better idea.

Comment: expanding and collapsing is not key here

Comment: If you actually need this, one option would be to take a generic tree-manipulation library, and then work out how to plug that into this format. You'd want to parse the text into a tree, and then re-generate the text output based on each tree manipulation. [Tree Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TreeMode) might well provide the first piece of the puzzle, but there would undoubtedly be a bunch of work involved in the second part.

Answer (score 0):

As for the second example, with Emacs you could jump from node to node using
M-x search-forward-regexp RET `\(-*\)\(\+\)\(-+>\)`

Than use something like narrow-to-region. Beside narrowing Emacs provides commands to hide stuff.

With some lisp based on this node-detection, you may read in a list with data found, etc.

Comment: You'll notice the trailing hyphens vary in number, so it would be more like `-*\+-+>`. Of course who knows whether that's actually generated output, or someone's ascii art for a compact tree representation.